# How to make the arguments of a function in the termina selectable with a tab button (with zsh)

Tags: c, terminal, tabs, arguments, zsh

I want to use the tab button in the terminal (`zsh` in my case) to select the argument available for a function in a terminal

For example, in the following example, I want that after having compiled the program with `gcc main.c -o main`, if I write `./main` and then press the tab button, I want that `hel` appears in the list of options to select it.

Here is `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if (argc == 2)
  {
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "hel") == 0)
    {
      printf("hello\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the ZSH documentation about tab-completion and how to configure it?

Comment: I have to say: I did not. Do you have a good link / tutorial to recomend to start with? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: A quick search for `zsh documentation` lead me to [this](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html).

Comment: If you want zsh to complete command-line arguments while a command is being typed, that is a zsh feature, and you implement it with zsh settings and not inside your program. There is no way for your program to control them, since your program is not running until the command line is completed and entered. (If you want your program to complete lines of input to your program, that requires interacting with the terminal in system-specific ways not defined by the C standard.)